# Is it possible to do lightweight REST calls in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, rest, remoting

We are converting a Flex application to use some REST APIs.

When adding the `mx.rpc.http.HTTPService` class to the code, the SWF binary output grew from 175KB to 260KB. This is an unacceptable hit.

Is there any better way to do lightweight REST calls from a Flex app? Are we better off using an external interface JS just to make the calls from there?

Comment: Are you talking about the binary output of your debug build or of a release build?  Release builds are much more optimized in my experience.  If you're comparing debug outputs, then I'd export release builds to verify that you actually have a problem before trying to solve it.

Comment: Also, if you want to optimize the SWF size, I suggest you have a look of how tu use Runtime Shared Libraries

Comment: @flextras - The sizes are updated to reflect a release build. @PeZ - RSL will not help us in this case, this is a single SWF scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`flash.net.URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) is built into the runtime and won't cause any increase in filesize. I've used it as a JSON client before, so you shouldn't have any troubles with it.

Below is a very simple example. See documentation for [`HTTP_STATUS`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3ahttpStatus) and [`HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3ahttpResponseStatus) for information on their restrictions.

```
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://tempuri.org/service/json");
request.method = "POST";
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.data = JSON.encode(jsonObject);

var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);

// Only supported by some browsers
loader.addEventHandler(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, statusCodeReceived);

// AIR only
loader.addEventHandler(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, statusCodeReceived);

loader.addEventHandler(Event.COMPLETE, function(ev:Event):void
{
    var responseJson : String = request.data as String;

    var responseJsonObject : String = JSON.decode(responseJson);
});

loader.addEventHandler(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
loader.addEventHandler(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
```

Comment: From what I remember , the official documentation provides an example of how to use it

Answer (score 2):

I've always thought a good approach to this would be to create a small interface to the browser's JavaScript HTTP API, XmlHttpRequest. I've never tried it, but I've looked into it, and it looked like it might be fairly straightforward.

This would have the added benefit of working around Flash Player's security restrictions which make its HTTP support terribly crippled.

Comment: IMO, this is a bad approach, because it complicates the code unnecesarily. Additionaly, AJAX/XmlHttpRequest has the same or more restrictions than the flash player net API (and you'd have to be granted access to JS to begin with, which) and is much more limited.

Comment: I disagree that XHR has more restrictions than the Flash Player. FP can't use PUT or DELETE, can't use the request header "Authorization," and can't access the response body if the status code is *anything* other than 200 (even 201).

Comment: I think this would be a good way to enable the use of the new HTTP/2 features.