# Adobe air and REST communication

Tags: apache-flex, rest, air, restful-authentication

Can someone recommend me a good example of Adobe air and REST API communication and authentication?. Googling this problem didn't help me.

Comment: http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/a-simple-actionscript-flex-rest-client/  this link also might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483098/is-it-possible-to-do-lightweight-rest-calls-in-flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to import REST Web Services into your Air project as Action Script classes. If you are using Flash Builder, it should be fairly easy to invoke REST Services.

Example: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=253

Comment: thanks @CodeToGlory. Can't I use `URLLoader` and `URLRequest` and do a rest communication?

Comment: You can http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#includeExamplesSummary